# Wine can't load UnityPlayer.dll in the same directory

Tags: 22.04, wine, games

So I have Ubuntu 22.04 and wine 8.0.2. I have a 64-bit wineprefix, because otherwise the program error differently. (However, I can try reverting back to 32-bit again). I have Visual C++ 2003 and 2013 installed via WineTricks.
The program I'm trying to execute is Stacklands.exe

```
0108:err:module:import_dll Loading library UnityPlayer.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\users\\dutchslav\\Games\\Stacklands.v1.4.1.18\\Stacklands.exe") failed (error c000012f).
0108:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\users\\dutchslav\\Games\\Stacklands.v1.4.1.18\\Stacklands.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.